# Selenium test case is not finding the chrome drive even though file exist on the server

Tags: linux, docker, selenium, jenkins, unix

I am trying to execute selenium test cases through Jenkins on an ec2 unix instance. I am getting the following error in Jenkins logs:

`Error in Launch Browser Driver: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: /home/ec2-user/workspace/PJTest/src/main/resources/drivers/chromedriver`

I ssh'ed to the server and created this folder manually and copied the chrome driver file. The job still gives the same error.

I have verified and the chromedriver file exist.

[image]

How do I debug this further to find out why Jenkins job is still unable to find this file?

Also, Jenkins is running inside docker on this ec2 instance. I am using the following command to start docker:

`docker run -d -v /var/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home:z -p 80:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v "/home/ec2-user/source/tyoc/jenkins" -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker -v $(which docker-compose):/usr/bin/docker-compose jenkins/jenkins:lts`

Comment: Is this in python ?

Comment: Nope. Pipeline script.